# PHP-FPM returns 200 but Nginx sending 504 gateway error

Tags: php, nginx

Looking at the Nginx log, I can see the following 504 error

```
139.47.72.206 - - [14/Dec/2022:02:36:56 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=shipping HTTP/2.0" 504 562 "https://connetixtiles.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=tax" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

However, if I look at the PHP-FPM access log

```
{"p":"23197","t":"14/Dec/2022:02:33:56 +0000","T":"14/Dec/2022:02:34:58 +0000","d":"1.826","r":"/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=shipping","m":"GET","R":"139.47.72.206","C":"84.87","M":"181579776","s":"200","X":"-"}
```

It seems that the PHP-FPM sends success but Nginx doesn't seem to be able to deliver it, so it times out after 3 minutes (max_execution_time is 180s)

It works for other pages.

Ideas?

Comment: Nginx should report more information about the error in the error log.

Comment: @RichardSmith no it doesn't. Just the generic 504 error: error] 2745#0: *2059 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 116.206.231.59, server: site.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=shipping HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm-site.sock", host: "site.com"